# Android ListView footer cutting off

Tags: android, mobile

im stuck at the minute trying to fix my `listview` for my android app, for some reason the lists in the app are now having the bottom cut off and are only showing half of the last list item (shown in image below)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk6Gk.png

I have looked at my xml and all seems to look fine

mix_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:geekui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cell_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mix_image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/blackburn_ravers_default_img" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.00"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <com.mobsandgeeks.ui.TypefaceTextView
                android:id="@+id/mix_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Blackburn Ravers"
                android:textColor="#000"
                geekui:customTypeface="fonts/titillium-semibold-webfont.ttf" />

            <com.mobsandgeeks.ui.TypefaceTextView
                android:id="@+id/mix_subtitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text=" "
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                geekui:customTypeface="fonts/titillium-regular-webfont.ttf" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_btn" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my java file is as follows

MixListAdapter.java

```
package com.enadun.blackburnravers.listviews;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import the.blackburnravers.mediaapp.R;

public class MixListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MixesList>{
    private MixesList[] mixList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    public MixListAdapter(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater, MixesList[] mixList){
        super(context, R.layout.mix_list_item, mixList);
        this.mixList = mixList;
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup){
        View localView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.mix_list_item, paramViewGroup, false);
        LinearLayout cell = (LinearLayout) localView.findViewById(R.id.cell_layout);
        ((TextView) localView.findViewById(R.id.mix_title)).setText(mixList[paramInt].getTitle());
        ((TextView) localView.findViewById(R.id.mix_subtitle)).setText(mixList[paramInt].getSubtitle());
        if(mixList[paramInt].isShowImage()){
            ((ImageView) localView.findViewById(R.id.mix_image)).setImageResource(getImageDrawable(mixList[paramInt].getImgName()));
        }

        switch (mixList[paramInt].getType())
        {
        case 1:
            cell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_background_header_xml);
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_background_body_xml);
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_background_footer_xml);
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_background_single_row_xml);
            break;
        }
        return localView;
    }

    private int getImageDrawable(String imgName) {
        return context.getResources().getIdentifier(imgName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());
    }
}
```

can anybody please see where i'm going wrong?
Cheers Rhys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit, new answer:**

It appears the solution to the OP's question was to remove the padding from the XML views.

**Original suggested answer:**

This looks like normal behavior to me.  Your list isn't going to automatically resize its rows to fully display each item.  I'm guessing if you scroll down you'll be able to see the rest of the list am I correct?  I suppose you could always update the resource xml driving the UI of each row by making the height of each row such that all items are in full view when you're scrolled to the top of your list.

Comment: You can see the whole list accept the bottom list row. It just cuts it in half, still clickable, but you can't scroll down any more to view the rest of it.
It's just strange, it was working fine up until yesterday. I haven't edited any code at all though, all I have done is change and edit some images in res folder, to updated the look and feel of it.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what happens if you remove all if the padding.  I've had issues before where having padding screwed up the way my views were being displayed.

Comment: I'll have a look into this later on when I get to my pc and let you know outcome.

Comment: I removed the padding and now the list is back to normal. Thanks for that bstar55.

Comment: Awesome!  I updated the answer to indicate the solution.